# Keep divs next to each other the same size without using a table?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to lay out my site in this way:

[image: Desired Layout]

The image div will contain a variable-sized image, and the image should be vertically and horizontally aligned. The text div will contain a lot of text.

This could easily be done with a table, but I'm trying to make this responsive so that once the site is too small horizontally that the textDiv will no longer float next to imageDiv and will then fall underneath.

The problem I'm having is that the the divs will just take up the required space of their content. How do I ensure that these two will remain the same size when they are floated next to each other?

Once the divs no longer float next to each other them being the same size wouldn't make sense anymore so that functionality would no longer be required.

I found Flex as a possible solution but it isn't well supported. I should mention that their widths will be set to a percentage of the parentDivs width.

Comment: Well... i would use display:table, and display:block for smaller screens + media queries to handle that change....

Comment: Have you considered using something like bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/)? No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by flexbox *isn't well supported*. It's supported by all major browsers [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). It would be a good solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using:

1. Absolute positioning with padding
2. Flex layout

```css
.parentDiv {border: 4px solid black;}
.imageDiv {border: 4px solid tomato;}
.textDiv {border: 4px solid skyblue;}
.imageDiv img { max-width: 100%; }
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 #first .imageDiv { width: 50%; max-width: 50%; box-sizing: border-box; }
 #first .parentDiv { position: relative; min-height: 150px; }
 #first .parentDiv > div { padding-left: 50%; }
 #first .imageDiv { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
 
 #second .parentDiv { display: flex; }
 #second .imageDiv, #second .textDiv { flex-basis: 50%; }
}
```

```html
<h2>Using absolute positioning and padding</h2>
<div id="first">
<div class="parentDiv"><div>
 <div class="imageDiv">
  <img src="http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png">
 </div>
 <div class="textDiv">
  

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quis cursus erat. In sit amet condimentum nulla, in elementum lorem. Duis iaculis, nibh nec iaculis semper, nisi neque fringilla metus, in faucibus urna urna non libero. Nullam aliquet ligula lorem, imperdiet lobortis ex malesuada ac. In sollicitudin eros eu dui iaculis, ac rutrum metus dapibus. Nam ac ex gravida, fringilla lectus nec, posuere sem. Nunc sit amet mi quis quam aliquet viverra. Duis congue gravida diam, eget ullamcorper leo faucibus vitae. Duis pretium lacus id nisl suscipit, lobortis rhoncus nisl blandit. Proin quis vestibulum purus, eu faucibus lectus. Vivamus enim turpis, suscipit nec cursus ac, sollicitudin at quam. Curabitur venenatis nisi tellus, a molestie ex mattis ac. Nulla nec dui ac tellus lacinia posuere at vel ante. Nulla iaculis eleifend dignissim.

Sed at lobortis neque. Nunc sapien ante, convallis at lobortis id, suscipit vitae augue. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris commodo vehicula felis, in iaculis turpis eleifend vitae. Sed non iaculis turpis, a accumsan ipsum. Vestibulum nec pretium tortor, in bibendum nulla. Suspendisse id tincidunt felis. Sed eleifend, ipsum sit amet condimentum accumsan, metus mi euismod mi, at ullamcorper odio nunc ut leo. Donec pellentesque imperdiet enim, nec varius leo semper eu. Aenean dictum, justo pellentesque cursus consequat, nunc nulla aliquam augue, eget dignissim metus erat ac libero. Aliquam tristique orci sapien, at pretium leo molestie et. Ut quis auctor nisl.

Proin quis placerat urna. Aliquam non posuere elit, tincidunt sollicitudin libero. Nunc vel mauris sit amet nunc varius blandit vel vel felis. Sed dictum, lorem vitae commodo eleifend, purus libero sagittis mauris, et mattis mauris tortor et enim. Donec vel tincidunt mauris. Proin aliquam dui sed lorem auctor, id congue leo fermentum. Ut laoreet purus quis justo malesuada, sed gravida eros hendrerit. Quisque eleifend pulvinar leo ut volutpat. Curabitur nec lectus augue. Donec congue turpis sed lectus lobortis molestie. Aenean posuere in enim quis mattis. Morbi dui eros, tincidunt id hendrerit nec, tempor a mauris. Maecenas vel sem mi. Maecenas lacinia non augue at egestas.

Phasellus vestibulum elementum feugiat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In ullamcorper sapien elit, nec pretium sapien sollicitudin in. Donec placerat urna eget erat tincidunt imperdiet. Pellentesque sed nisi congue quam accumsan tristique sed ac diam. Nunc auctor non leo et ornare. Nam ornare pharetra lacus ut commodo. Sed sem nunc, porttitor a venenatis vel, cursus sed dui.

Morbi congue augue in tortor porta, vel condimentum orci feugiat. Donec lacinia nisl sed orci venenatis lobortis. Ut nulla eros, malesuada ut vestibulum cursus, laoreet et augue. Nullam varius dapibus lorem sit amet vestibulum. Pellentesque ultricies eu elit ac ullamcorper. Pellentesque viverra ultrices augue, ac vestibulum mi pretium ut. Vestibulum et ex eget tortor sodales convallis non a quam. Nam facilisis gravida lacinia. Quisque accumsan massa et accumsan interdum. Mauris vestibulum volutpat metus, vel pretium urna auctor eget. Vestibulum aliquet fringilla tristique. Nam ipsum quam, faucibus eget magna sed, facilisis molestie lacus. 
 </div>
</div></div>
</div>
<h2>Using flex layout</h2>
<p><b>Firefox specific problem:</b> the width of the image interfere with <code>flex-basis</code> of <code>imageDiv</code>.
<br>Give the width of the image in percentage.</p>
<div id="second">
<div class="parentDiv">
 <div class="imageDiv">
  <img src="http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png">
 </div>
 <div class="textDiv">
  

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quis cursus erat. In sit amet condimentum nulla, in elementum lorem. Duis iaculis, nibh nec iaculis semper, nisi neque fringilla metus, in faucibus urna urna non libero. Nullam aliquet ligula lorem, imperdiet lobortis ex malesuada ac. In sollicitudin eros eu dui iaculis, ac rutrum metus dapibus. Nam ac ex gravida, fringilla lectus nec, posuere sem. Nunc sit amet mi quis quam aliquet viverra. Duis congue gravida diam, eget ullamcorper leo faucibus vitae. Duis pretium lacus id nisl suscipit, lobortis rhoncus nisl blandit. Proin quis vestibulum purus, eu faucibus lectus. Vivamus enim turpis, suscipit nec cursus ac, sollicitudin at quam. Curabitur venenatis nisi tellus, a molestie ex mattis ac. Nulla nec dui ac tellus lacinia posuere at vel ante. Nulla iaculis eleifend dignissim.

Sed at lobortis neque. Nunc sapien ante, convallis at lobortis id, suscipit vitae augue. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Mauris commodo vehicula felis, in iaculis turpis eleifend vitae. Sed non iaculis turpis, a accumsan ipsum. Vestibulum nec pretium tortor, in bibendum nulla. Suspendisse id tincidunt felis. Sed eleifend, ipsum sit amet condimentum accumsan, metus mi euismod mi, at ullamcorper odio nunc ut leo. Donec pellentesque imperdiet enim, nec varius leo semper eu. Aenean dictum, justo pellentesque cursus consequat, nunc nulla aliquam augue, eget dignissim metus erat ac libero. Aliquam tristique orci sapien, at pretium leo molestie et. Ut quis auctor nisl.

Proin quis placerat urna. Aliquam non posuere elit, tincidunt sollicitudin libero. Nunc vel mauris sit amet nunc varius blandit vel vel felis. Sed dictum, lorem vitae commodo eleifend, purus libero sagittis mauris, et mattis mauris tortor et enim. Donec vel tincidunt mauris. Proin aliquam dui sed lorem auctor, id congue leo fermentum. Ut laoreet purus quis justo malesuada, sed gravida eros hendrerit. Quisque eleifend pulvinar leo ut volutpat. Curabitur nec lectus augue. Donec congue turpis sed lectus lobortis molestie. Aenean posuere in enim quis mattis. Morbi dui eros, tincidunt id hendrerit nec, tempor a mauris. Maecenas vel sem mi. Maecenas lacinia non augue at egestas.

Phasellus vestibulum elementum feugiat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In ullamcorper sapien elit, nec pretium sapien sollicitudin in. Donec placerat urna eget erat tincidunt imperdiet. Pellentesque sed nisi congue quam accumsan tristique sed ac diam. Nunc auctor non leo et ornare. Nam ornare pharetra lacus ut commodo. Sed sem nunc, porttitor a venenatis vel, cursus sed dui.

Morbi congue augue in tortor porta, vel condimentum orci feugiat. Donec lacinia nisl sed orci venenatis lobortis. Ut nulla eros, malesuada ut vestibulum cursus, laoreet et augue. Nullam varius dapibus lorem sit amet vestibulum. Pellentesque ultricies eu elit ac ullamcorper. Pellentesque viverra ultrices augue, ac vestibulum mi pretium ut. Vestibulum et ex eget tortor sodales convallis non a quam. Nam facilisis gravida lacinia. Quisque accumsan massa et accumsan interdum. Mauris vestibulum volutpat metus, vel pretium urna auctor eget. Vestibulum aliquet fringilla tristique. Nam ipsum quam, faucibus eget magna sed, facilisis molestie lacus. 
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The image div will contain a variable-sized image, and the image
>   should be vertically and horizontally aligned. The text div will
>   contain a lot of text.
>
> This could easily be done with a table, but I'm trying to make this
>   responsive so that once the site is too small horizontally that the
>   textDiv will no longer float next to imageDiv and will then fall
>   underneath.

If it is easily done with a table layout for you, then just use a table layout. Make it responsive by adding an appropriate media query and change the layout. By table layout I mean `display: table` (not the `table` element).

It will be as easy as:

```
#parent { display: table; }
#parent > div { display: table-cell; width: 50%; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Do take care to have a `max-width` specified on the image to keep it within bounds:

```
#imgWrap { text-align: center; }
#imgWrap > img { max-width: 100%; }
```

The `vertical-align` and `text-align` will help you control the alignment of the image.

> The problem I'm having is that the the divs will just take up the
>   required space of their content. How do I ensure that these two will
>   remain the same size when they are floated next to each other?

Fixing the width with the `display: table-cell` will take care of that.

> Once the divs no longer float next to each other them being the same
>   size wouldn't make sense anymore so that functionality would no longer
>   be required.

Just add a media query for the break point that you need and simply reset the `display` back to `block`:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    #parent { display: block; }
    #parent > div { display: block; width: auto; }
}
```

**Snippet**:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
#parent { border: 1px solid #00f; width: 75%; margin: 0 auto; display: table; }
#parent > div { 
    border: 1px solid #f00; 
    display: table-cell; width: 50%; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#imgWrap { text-align: center; }
#imgWrap > img { max-width: 100%; }

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    #parent { display: block; }
    #parent > div { display: block; width: auto; }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="imgWrap">
        <img src="//lorempixel.com/240/120" />
    </div>
    <div id="contentWrap">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quis cursus erat. In sit amet condimentum nulla, in elementum lorem. Duis iaculis, nibh nec iaculis semper, nisi neque fringilla metus, in faucibus urna urna non libero. Nullam aliquet ligula lorem, imperdiet lobortis ex malesuada ac. In sollicitudin eros eu dui iaculis, ac rutrum metus dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean quis cursus erat. 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/29vLq11o/3/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but you can set the width of each to 50% and then float them left. They will retain their size side-by-side until the screen becomes to small:

```
.image {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
.image img {
    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
}
.text {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rhn76m5z/3/

Comment: *`"The image div will contain a variable-sized image, and the image should be vertically and horizontally aligned. The text div will contain a lot of text."`*